# how should I pay my online visa fee?

Tags: us-permanent-residents, bangladesh

I'm applying for Bangladesh visa. They mentioned in the website payment must be by money order. Should I mail them the money order cheque?

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you found the money order information? Also provide details of your nationality (because some nationals don't require to pay any fee) and the embassy where you are applying.